# Prawn PDF generator: Make image with link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I use [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) to generate pdf and I want to include an image with link.I didn't
find a way to do it in its official documentation.Helps appreciated

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289031/rails-gem-prawn-image-and-anchor, which deals exactly with this

Comment: may be this link help you:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289031/rails-gem-prawn-image-and-anchor

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, we don't have high level support for image linking, but we do have support  close to the PDF level.

So, you'd have to do something pretty terrible like this in the current Prawn release (0.14.0):

```
require "prawn"
require "open-uri"

Prawn::Document.generate("x.pdf") do
  image(open("http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/images/example_pdf.png"), 
        :width => 300, :height => 300)
  link_annotation([bounds.absolute_left, 
                  bounds.absolute_top - 300, 
                  bounds.absolute_left + 300, bounds.absolute_top], 
                      :Border => [0,0,0], 
                      :A => { :Type => :Action, :S => :URI, 
                        :URI =>
                            PDF::Core::LiteralString.new("http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com") } )

end
```

Obviously, we'd be interested in a patch that would implement this feature at a higher level. Prawn has a lot of half-done stuff in it because the project went mostly inactive for a couple years, but we're now actively working on it again and welcome contributions!

Our repository is located here: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn